# Error has occurred during compile Azure DevOps Widget: Can't resolve 'TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers'

Tags: html, typescript, webpack, azure-devops-extensions, react-typescript

I'm newbie in React and TypeScript. Could you please help me to understand what’s going on with my code?

HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        VSS.init({
            explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
            usePlatformStyles: true
        });
        // Entry point to widget
        VSS.require(["dist/Widget/Widget"], function () {
            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root" class="widget"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

TSX file:

```
/// <reference types="vss-web-extension-sdk" />

import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import WidgetHelpers = require('TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers');
import WidgetContracts = require('TFS/Dashboards/WidgetContracts');

interface IHelloWorldViewModelProps {
    name: string
}

export class HelloWorldViewModel extends React.Component<IHelloWorldViewModelProps> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <span>Hello, {this.props.name}</span>
        )
    }
}

export class Widget {

    public load(widgetSettings: WidgetContracts.WidgetSettings) {
        return this.render(widgetSettings);
    }

    private render(widgetSettings: WidgetContracts.WidgetSettings) : IPromise<WidgetContracts.WidgetStatus> {

        let userName = VSS.getWebContext().user.name;

        ReactDOM.render(
            <HelloWorldViewModel name={userName} />,
            document.getElementById('root'));

        return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
    }
}

WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();

VSS.register("Widget", function () {
    return new Widget();
});
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

// Webpack entry points. Mapping from resulting bundle name to the source file entry.
const entries = {};

// Loop through subfolders in the "Samples" folder and add an entry for each one
const samplesDir = path.join(__dirname, "src");
fs.readdirSync(samplesDir).filter(dir => {
    if (fs.statSync(path.join(samplesDir, dir)).isDirectory()) {
        entries[dir] = "./" + path.relative(process.cwd(), path.join(samplesDir, dir, dir));
    }
});

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        filename: "[name]/[name].js"
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
        https: true,
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "/dist/"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        alias: {
            "vss-web-extension-sdk": path.resolve("node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk")
        },
    },
    stats: {
        warnings: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "azure-devops-ui/buildScripts/css-variables-loader", "sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "**/*.html", context: "src" }])
    ]
};
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "charset": "utf8",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "rootDir": "src/",
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.promise"
        ],
        "types": [
            "react"
        ]
    }
}
```

It gives me error like this:

```
ERROR in ./src/Widget/Widget.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers' in 'D:\widget_example\src\Widget'
 @ ./src/Widget/Widget.tsx 12:0-46:2
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

But if I remove references to `WidgetHelpers` module, it works fine:

```
/// <reference types="vss-web-extension-sdk" />

import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import WidgetHelpers = require('TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers');
import WidgetContracts = require('TFS/Dashboards/WidgetContracts');

interface IHelloWorldViewModelProps {
    name: string
}

export class HelloWorldViewModel extends React.Component<IHelloWorldViewModelProps> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <span>Hello, {this.props.name}</span>
        )
    }
}

export class Widget {

    public load(widgetSettings: WidgetContracts.WidgetSettings) {
        return this.render(widgetSettings);
    }

    private render(widgetSettings: WidgetContracts.WidgetSettings) : boolean {

        let userName = VSS.getWebContext().user.name;

        ReactDOM.render(
            <HelloWorldViewModel name={userName} />,
            document.getElementById('root'));

        return true;
    }
}

VSS.register("Widget", function () {
    return new Widget();
});
```

[image: Widget without WidgetHelpers]

I was referencing to example from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/analytics-example-widget)

Could you please point me where I missed something?

Let me know if you need some additional information.

**Update 1**

I did manage to resolve module `TFS/Build/RestClient` by this way:

```
/// <reference types="vss-web-extension-sdk" />

import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import WidgetHelpers = require('TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers');
import WidgetContracts = require('TFS/Dashboards/WidgetContracts');
import AdoBuildClient = require('TFS/Build/RestClient');
import AdoBuildContracts = require('TFS/Build/Contracts');

let buildClient: AdoBuildClient.BuildHttpClient4;

VSS.require("TFS/Build/RestClient", function (AdoBuildClient: { getClient: () => AdoBuildClient.BuildHttpClient4; }) {
    buildClient = AdoBuildClient.getClient();
    buildClient.getDefinitions("MyFirstProject", "TestWidget").then(definitions => {
        console.log(definitions[0].id);
    })
});

...
```

But I don't understand what's going on, code turned into a mess but it works.

**Update 2**

Project which reproduces the issue can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmDgkcQMVvJXgR-zg_8mTL5v9vKC?e=GfwxaI)

**Update 3**

Modules `TFS/...` are loaded in runtime so there is no way to resolve them during compilation I think. I've dropped old version SDK `vss-web-extension-sdk` and moved my project to new one `azure-devops-extension-sdk`. There is no such issues in new version.

Comment: Hi, You can configure resolve.extensions to look for .ts. Don't forget to add the default values as well, otherwise most modules will break because they rely on the fact that the .js extension is automatically used.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT, hi, I already configured it to look for .ts files as you can see in webpack.config.js but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

I know this may sound dumb, but double check that the WidgetHelpers is actually in the path you provided "TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers". I have had an issue where I had to do a Save As again to that path, but the error you got ***"ERROR in ./src/Widget/Widget.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers' in 'D:\widget_example\src\Widget'
@ ./src/Widget/Widget.tsx 12:0-46:2
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile."*** is the *./src/Widget/Widget.tsx* a repo?
What that error is saying is that it failed to compile because it can find the path *TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers* which it thinks is in *D:\widget_example\src\Widget* and then it throws *@ ./src/Widget/Widget.tsx* again as the target it was going for. So you can check and make sure the path is correct (the module is there **and** it is spelled correctly), that no files in that path are corrupted.

Comment: There is no module locally since it's loaded runtime. See my third update

Comment: Right, which is why I asked if it is a repo, aka are you pulling the info from the net. I can only assume that this worked, or at least that you solved your issue seeing as how my comment is now labeled an "Answer". If not I'd be glad to continue to help.